# What is the namespace of NUnit CollectionAssert?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

but still can not get `CollectionAssert` which I found on [CollectionAssert (NUnit 2.4)](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4.1)

The printscreen:
[image: in my VS2008]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely in the `NUnit.Framework` namespace in the `nunit.framework` assembly - I've just downloaded NUnit 2.5.10 to check.

I suggest you check which version of `nunit.framework` you're really referencing, and open it up in Reflector to check for the existence of `CollectionAssert`.

Comment: Or perhaps open it in ILSpy? ;)

Comment: Well, you are right. I refer to `nunit` from `Selenium`, and it's the old version. I'm now refering to nunit 2.5. Find it now. Thanks!